# Spring:Display List<ObjectID> in jsp view

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new bie to spring. My domain is

```
@Document
public class Post {

     @Id
     private ObjectId _id;
     private String postTitle;
     private String postDesc;
     private ObjectId owner=Global.getCurruser();
     private List<ObjectId> intrestReceived=new ArrayList<ObjectId>();

// Getters and setters
}
```

my controller looks like

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/post/intrestReceived", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String intrestReceived(Model model){
        List<Post> result=postService.intrestReceived();
        model.addAttribute("result", result);
        return "intrestReceived";
    }
```

and my view looks like :

```
<form:form id="idForm" class="form-horizontal" method="GET">
        <table border=1>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Post ID</b></td>
                <td><b>Post Desc</b></td>
                <td><b>Intrest Received</b></td>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach items="${result}" var="result">
                <tr>
                    <td>${result.getId()}</td>
                    <td>${result.postDesc}</td>
                    <td>${result.getIntrestReceived()}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </form:form>
```

Here `<td>${result.getIntrestReceived()}</td>` returns the `List<ObjectId>`  how can I iterate it to get individual id in seperate row. 
Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<c:forEach items="${result}" var="item">
                <tr>
                    <td>${item._id}</td>
                    <td>${item.postDesc}</td>
                  <c:forEach items="${result.intrestReceived}" var="intr">
                    <tr><td>${intr._id}</td></tr>
          </c:forEach>
                </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: tried your code but giving exception An exception occurred processing JSP page at line <td>${item._id}</td> Root Cause Property '_id' not found on type com.cheasyy.fk.Post

Comment: change that name to corresponding id name in your Post class

Comment: thanks , I corrected my mistake but now it is showing error at line '<tr><td>${intr._id}</td></tr>' Root cause 'Property '_id' not found on type org.bson.types.ObjectId'

Comment: That is because _id is not present in your objectId class.What value do you require to be printed from ObjectId class, give that name.

Comment: I am using default class  org.bson.types.ObjectId class do I need to create my own class? sorry for stupid question but I am newbie.

Comment: What value do you require from ObjectId class to be shown in your UI?

Comment: hey I solved the problem using <tr><td>${intr.get()}</td></tr> thank you very much for your valuable time and help.